# JS максимальное время выполнения скрипта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имеется preloader на сайте, но приблизительно в 1 из 30 случаев он висит около 4-5 секунд, хотелось бы ограничить максимальное время выполнения. Как реализовать это посредством js? Нужно чтобы скрипт работал до загрузки страницы или выключался принудительно если прошло 2 секунды.

Comment: Надо узнать в чём проблема, а не бороться с последствиями.

Comment: До проблема в том что присутствует часть страницы с другого сайта, которая долго грузится... Если ограничить время работы скрипта, будет вообще отлично.

Comment: Тогда какой смысл убирать лодер, если та часть всё ещё не загружена и в любом случае надо ждать?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
~function () {
  var t = setTimeout(function () { $.ready() }, 2000)
  $(function () { clearTimeout(t) })
}()
```